# Importin mutliple files in an android app

Tags: android, file

I got an app that imports should import images.
The paths of the images that I want to import are stored in a csv file.
The path of the images is relative to the of the csv file.

```
import.csv
importFolder/
importFolder/pic1.jpg
importFolder/pic2.jpg
```

I get the input.csv file given as an Uri. But I fail to build read the images with the relative path.
This is what I tried:

```
String parentPath = new File(inputURI.getPath()).getParent();
parentPath += "/";
                        

File importImagePath = new File(parentPath, relativeImageOath);
File storageDir = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

File newFile = ImageUtil.copyFile(importImagePath, storageDir, importImagePath.getName());
```

This fails with a file not found exception, even though the importImagePath is the same as showing in the file explorer of android.

Maybe read that it is a bad idea to convert uris to Files, but I don't know how else I should do it.
I am open for suggestions es well, to ajust the export but I don't want to base64 the images or something and write them in one big file.

Comment: Could be that the inputURI you are using to get the parent path of the CSV file is not a `file://` URI, but rather a `content://` URI?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the `inputURI` you are using to get the parent path of the CSV file is not a `file://` URI, but rather a `content://` URI? If this is the case then calling `getParent()` would not return the actual path on the device, rather than  an encoded path that is specific to the content provider.
You could try using a `ContentResolver` to open an `InputStream` and then read the content of the CSV  from the `InputStream`.

```java
try {
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(inputURI);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  String relativeImagePath = line.trim();
        Uri images = Uri.withAppendedPath(inputURI, relativeImagePath);
        InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(images);
        // Copy the contents of the imageInputStream to your app's storage directory
    }
    reader.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Uri.withAppendedPath causes a problem because we append to the csv file not the parent path of csv-file